# Parsley.js Customer Validator Pass Variable to message

Tags: parsley.js

```
window.Parsley.addValidator('passwordValidChars', {
    requirementType: ['integer', 'integer'],
    validateString: function(value, min, max) {
        var invalidChars = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if(value.charCodeAt(i) < min || value.charCodeAt(i) > max) {
                invalidChars.push(value.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return (invalidChars.length === 0)
    },
    messages: {
        en: 'These characters are not allowed %s'
    }
});
```

I have this custom validator which validates the password entered between specific char codes e.g [33, 126].

If the user entered any invalid characters I collect them to an array invalidChars and then I want to pass the invalidChars array to the error message but how can I do that? The only values I can pass to the message are the min and max.

Answer (score 1):

There's no super easy way, but you can return a dynamic error message. It's not well documented, but instead of returning `false` return `$.Deferred().reject('your dynamic error message')`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will check it out. The downside is that I wont be able to use the message locale if I ever want to add the same message on different language.